# Type.GetType() throws when typeName represents an array type with an invalid size

Tags: c#, reflection

The documentation for [System.Type.GetType(string, bool)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5cf8k43(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) says, that `TypeLoadException` is thrown when `throwOnError` is `true` and:

> {...} typeName represents an array type with an invalid size

I wonder, what does it mean and how is it possible?
Is is related to unmanaged code or to reflection-based working with array?
Do I have to worry about this case when I want to get `Type` by its name?

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Comment: I think invalid sizes in arrays occur when you use a size that is considered off limits. Things like negative values, or values that are too large for a certain array type to hold.

Comment: @Char The only problem with that is that array sizes are not part of the type. `new int[100]` and `new int[1000]` produce the same type: `int[]`. Only array dimensions are part of the type: `new int[100,100]` produces type `int[,]`.

Comment: I still don't get it, how does the method know size of array, when I only want to get type information only by type name? Maybe it would be more correct to ask, what value I have to pass to `typeName` so that it matches the case in the subject?

Comment: @hvd Ah, that is interesting I did not realize that. Thank-you for the clarification

Comment: @hvd That's true in C#, at least, but the .NET runtime itself permits array types to specify lower and upper bounds, so maybe that's the case where the exception will be thrown? See [Array.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Int32___System_Int32___).

Comment: That method has a weird syntax for specifying array lower bounds.  The docs say that `Type.GetType("MyArray[*]")` specifies an "A one-dimensional array with an unknown lower bound".  I figured this might do it `var t = Type.GetType("System.Int32[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,]", true);` but the exception just says that it "has too many dimensions"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Flydog57 mentioned,

```
Type.GetType("System.Int32[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,]")
```

will produce an exception, since maximum number of dimensions for the array is 32. It doesn't really correspond to the doc saying

> typeName represents an array type with an invalid size

but I think there is enough evidence that it is exactly the case we are looking for:

- It produces exactly `TypeLoadException` and doesn't fit any other described case
- The only thing in C# that may sound like "array type with a size" is [fixed size buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers), but this is not the case.

So, I 'm pretty sure that there is a mistake in the doc and the correct variant should sound like

> typeName represents an array type with an invalid dimension size